# проблема с импортом aiogram и запуском проекта

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пишу бота на aiogram 2.24, и у меня проблема с импортом. Я установил aiogram нужной версии (pip install aiogram==2.24), и буквально вчера всё работало, а сейчас я открываю тот же самый код в том же самом проекте, а он выдаёт ошибку и говорит что во-первых при запуске не удаётся найти указанный файл, во-вторых aiogram неизвестная библиотека и её нельзя импортировать, хотя терминал успешно её установил. Вся фишка в том, что буквально вчера всё работало, а сегодня тот же самый код без изменений выдаёт всё вышеперечисленное, я ума не приложу что делать. Возможно ли ошибка в базе данных? Раньше она не работала т. к. файл был повреждён, сейчас я её пересоздал

Изменено: сейчас я перешёл в другую среду разработки, теперь ошибка только при импорте (File "c:\projects\scambot27-02-2024\pythonProject\bot\main.py", line 1, in 
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram').
Классика, но я не знаю что с этим делать, всё же установлено

Мой код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import asyncio
import sqlite3

TOKEN_API = "TOKEN"

bot = Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)





@dp.message_handler()
async def mess(message: types.Message):
    if message.text=='/start':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Проверяем, есть ли уже такая учетная запись по username
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username={message.from_user.username}")
        existing_account = cursor.fetchone()

        # Если учетная запись не существует, добавляем новую запись в базу данных
        if not existing_account:
            name=message.from_user.first_name+" "+message.from_user.last_name
            cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO accounts (username, name) VALUES ({message.from_user.username}, {name})")
            conn.commit()
            print("Учетная запись успешно добавлена")
        else:
            print("Учетная запись уже существует")

        conn.close()
    else:
        await message.answer(text="неизвестная команда")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Как вы понимаете, вместо TOKEN в кавычках указан токен моего бота

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности, заголовок «проблема с тем-то» - весьма малоинформативен,

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin так в том и дело что я вообще понятия не имею в чём тут может быть проблема

Comment: «а он выдаёт ошибку» - вот и проблема. вот про неё и задавайте вопрос. именно про эту не описанную вами ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из

> File "c:\projects\scambot27-02-2024\pythonProject\bot\main.py", line 1, in from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram')

Вывод следующий:
Окружение, которое вы используете не имеет модуля aiogram.
Возможно вы установили aiogram на venv, а теперь пытаетесь использовать глобальное окружение. Или наоборот - установили глобально, но при создании venv'a не подтянули модули, установленные глобально. Другой проблемы быть не может. Разбирайтесь с тем, какое из существующих у вас окружений выполняет код.

Можете установить aiogram через cmd, создать новое виртуальное окружение с флагом "inherit global site-packages" и использовать его.

Более правильный вариант - разобраться с конфигурацией интерпретатора проекта. В пайчарме вкладка "Edit configurations", ее нужно изучить детально, смотрите скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, помогло